# С# Windows Forms Живой поиск

Tags: c#, winforms

Предположим, есть коллекция или массив значений. Как можно организовать "живой поиск" в comboBox как в поисковой системе google? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все решил попроще. Используется стандартный контрол, при изменении значения выполняется следующий метод:

```
class Class_CleverSearch
{

    public void Search(DataRow[] datarows, //Перечень наименований для отборки
                             int i_max,    //Максимальное количество позиций в списке 
                             ComboBox cb   //ComboBox, значение которое набрано
                             ) //Максимальное количество позиций в списке) 
    {

        cb.Items.Clear();

        int i_kol = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            cb.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            i_kol++;
            if (i_kol > i_max)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        cb.DroppedDown = true; //Принудительно раскрываем ComboBox
        cb.SelectionStart = cb.Text.Length;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Для этого Вам нужно сделать следующее:

```
var values = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
values.AddRange(ВашаКоллекцияСтрок);
_comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = values;
_comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
_comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все четко.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: Спасибо. Еще попутный вопрос. Сразу на примере. ComboBox отображает список городов. Если набрать первый символ, к примеру Б, то отобразятся все города начинающиеся на данную букву. Необходимо, чтобы отображались все города, содержащие букву Б не зависимо от ее положения.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов мне кажется, что без дополнительных телодвижений стандартные элементы управления так не умеют делать.

Comment: Вам не кажется. Есть хоть какие- то идеи как это реализовать. Не прошу решение, а только предложите в каком направлении искать. Спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов если есть потребность в таком функционале - то как вариант можно попробовать рассмотреть использование сторонних компонентов. А если нужно на стандартных компонентах - тут надо подумать. Я попробую попозже посмотреть. Но в силу приближающихся выходных не могу обещать, что будет быстро ;( Вы можете попробовать создать отдельный вопрос по этому поводу, чтобы другие участники сообщества тоже могли в этом поучаствовать ;)

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Если вам подошёл этот ответ, можете его отметить как принятый?

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно было. Это случай строгого соответствия. Будет время выложу к ответу скрин того, что хотел и как реализовал.

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так:

```
comboBox1.DataSourse=_dt;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Это нужно для фильтрования значений в списке в зависимости от вводимого значения.

Еще: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread326296.html

**Для внимательных:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBoxSearch
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод,позволяющий организовать поиск в listBox.
    /// Автор: Umnick
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBox">ListBox в котором осуществляется поиск.</param>
    public void Search(ListBox listBox, List<string> q)
    {
        //Объявление переменных и заполнение их для поиска
        bool flag = false;
        List<int> c = new List<int>();    //Колличество совпадений
        List<string> match = new List<string>();//Список с совпадениями
        int n = 0; //Сюда запишем наибольшее кол-во совпадений
        double p = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0; //Сюда запишем индекс элемента в listbox,в котором найдено наибольшее кол-во совпадений
        List<string> s = new List<string>();//будем переписывать все items из listbox сюда
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)  //цикл,в нем заполним наши списки
        {
            s.Add(listBox.Items[i].ToString());//заполняем items
            c.Add(0);//заполняем наш счетчик нулями
        }
        //Основные циклы по работке с поиском
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)//Цикл,им проходимся по каждому символу в строке поиска
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.Count; j++)//Цикл,проходимся по каждому item в нашей коллекции,ранее мы переписали туда все items
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < s[j].Length; k++)//Цикл,посимвольно перебираем значение каждого items и ищем совпадения.
                {
                    if (s[j][k] == textBox1.Text[i] || char.ToLower(s[j][k]) == textBox1.Text[i] || char.ToUpper(s[j][k]) == textBox1.Text[i])//Проверка на совпадение.Если один из символов items`а совпал с одним из символов строки поиска,увеличиваем наш счетчик
                    {
                        c[j] = ++c[j];//Увеличиваем счетчик,каждый индекс которого,соответствует каждому items в listBox1.
                        count++;
                        flag = true;
                    }

                }
                if (c[j] > n)//Поиск найбольшего счетчика,тоесть items,в котором было обнаружено наибольшее кол-во совпадений.
                {
                    n = c[j];//...
                    index = j;//Записываем в переменную,индекс,как и говорилось ранее.
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < c.Count; i++)
            {
                p += c[i];
            }
            p /= c.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
            {
                if (c[i] != 0)
                {
                    listBox.Items.Add(s[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) 
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(q[i]);
            }
        }
        flag = false;
   }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Search(listBox1,items);//Вызываем наш метод,и начинаем поиск.
    }
    public List<string> items = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Какой принцип фильтрации? Первый символ значения из списка соответствует первому вводимому значению в ComboBox? По поводу ссылки спасибо, но там на примере ListBox. Хочется реализовать красиво в ComboBox.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, да

Comment: К сожалению нужен фильтр с частичным совпадением.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, например? если буква в середине?

Comment: Да, если буква в середине.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, а ссылку смотрел? зачем же я ее прикрепил? самое последнее сообщение в теме.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, обновил ответ

Comment: Вопрос в том, что при вводе значения необходимо, чтобы без дополнительных телодвижений сам выпадал список и в нем был результат поиска. В данном примере, что вы дали после ввода значения в ComboBox мне нужно раскрывать список и смотреть "а если там что?". Или я не прав? И этот листбокс абсолютно не нужен мне на форме. Считайте, что есть список с уже отобранными значениями, вопрос в том, как заставить ComboBox постоянно быть раскрытым, если так можно выразиться.